# Can't push local project to gitlab

Tags: gitlab, push

i'm trying to push a local project to a gitlab repository. I followed the usual commands provided with each new Project. Everything worked just fine until the last command; I acctually dicovered the local project is being pushed to a gitlab project that I actually deleted.

And each time I create a new project and try to push to it, the files are directed to the one I deleted but is somehow re-created with every push.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please include the output of `git remote show origin` and `git push`? What software/operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the following [guide](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html). Although is for github, is almost identical for gitlab. (understanding git is the key). I think you need to re-formulate your question better:

You have the following remote: `origin` with path `https://<your-gitlab-project-repo-path>.git`. Then locally, you run:

`cd your-project
git init .
git remote add origin https://<your-gitlab-project-repo-path>.git
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master`

Done.